# Phone regular expression with dots and slashes

Tags: regex

I have this simple regular expression to check phone numbers: `\+?(?:\d ?){7,20}`

It´s working with phones like:

- 0034 123 456 789
- +34123456789

and a mix of that.

I would like to include extend my validation detecting "." or "-". Example:

- 0034.123.456.789
- 123-456-789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use a character class instead of the final space of your non-matching group :

```
\+?(?:\d[ .-]?){7,20}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
\+?(?:\d ? ?[.-]?){7,20}
```

Comment: I’m curious, is there a special reason for the ` ? ?` ?